# How do I Get This HTML 5 Form To Give PHP The Input Data Then Display It On The Screen

Tags: php, html, forms

How do I Get This HTML 5 Form To Give PHP The Input Data Then Display It On The Screen. I want to collect data in a form. Convert it into a php variable and then echo it out in a way that I can read it.

```
  <form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
</form>

<body>
<pre>

<?php
$taco = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) . '!';
$taco = $_POST;
echo $taco;
?>

</pre>

</body
</html>
```

Comment: please find a 'basic' php form tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
<?php
if($_POST) { // check if the page is posted not with a $_GET
    foreach($_POST as $field => $value) { // Foreach field
        $value = strip_tags($value); // Strip html tags (you can add more)

        echo 'Field: '.$field.' has value: '.$value.'<br>'; // output
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Display">
</form>
```

Just put it all in one php file. You can add as many fields as you want.